# How can I detect programmatically if microphone/camera is enabled on macOS?

Tags: macos, avfoundation

I'm in need of detecting if a microphone and/or camera is active but the only thing I found is iOS related only. The Apple documentation have examples (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions) but this seems iOS only too. It seems there's no AVAudioSession on macOS. Can somebody give me a hint how can I achieve this?